# Total Number and Total Value pl/sql

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I made a query within a cursor that calculates the total number of cancellations, cancels or returned items and the total value. However, I cannot get the right value for the totals of the items that been cancelled, return or all cancelled

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE NUM_OF_RET_CAN(PRAM_DATE IN DATE)
             AS
     CURSOR CUR2 IS
     SELECT I.CONDITION, I.DEL_DATE, SUM(DE.QUANTITY) NUMBER_OF_PRO,       
            SUM(NVL(DE.QUANTITY,0) * NVL (P.COSTS,0)) TOTAL
      FROM ITEMS I, DE_DETAILS DE, PARTS P
      WHERE DE.PRO_NO = P.PRO_NO 
      AND I.ITEMS_NO = DE.ITEM_NO 
      AND TO_CHAR(I.DEL_DATE, 'mm-yyyy') = TO_CHAR(PRAM_DATE, 'mm-yyyy') 
      GROUP BY I.CONDITION, I.DEL_DATE;

     CAL_CUR CUR2%ROWTYPE;

     BEGIN
     OPEN CUR2;
      FETCH CUR2 INTO CAL_CUR; 

    IF VARCUR1.CONDITION ='CANCELL' THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CANCELLED: '||CAL_CUR.NUMBER_OF_PRO );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total: '|| CAL_CUR.TOTAL);
    ELSIF VARCUR1.CONDITION ='ORDER RETURNED' THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('RETURNED              : '|| 
     CAL_CUR.NUMBER_OF_PRO);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total                  : '||  CAL_CUR.TOTAL);

    ELSIF VARCUR1.CONDITION = 'ALL ORDERS ARE CANCELLED!' THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ALL CANCELLATIONS         : '|| 
    CAL_CUR.NUMBER_OF_PRO );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total                   : '||  CAL_CUR.TOTAL);
   ELSE
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No records for this month');
  END IF; 
 CLOSE CUR2;
END NUM_OF_RET_CAN;
```

If I run the select Query without using the cursor or the procedure I get this result:

```
   CONDITION               DEL_DATE              NUMBER_OF_PRO       TOTAL
  ------------            -------------       ------------------- --------- 
 ALL ORDERS ARE CANCELLED!   12-JAN-16               4                99.96 
 ALL ORDERS ARE CANCELLED!   10-JAN-16               2                44.98
```

Expected Answer

```
    CONDITION               DEL_DATE              NUMBER_OF_PRO       TOTAL
  ------------            -------------       ------------------- --------- 
 ALL ORDERS ARE CANCELLED!     JAN-16                6              144.94
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to group by month rather than day, eg:

```
select   i.condition,
         trunc(i.del_date, 'mm') del_date,
         sum(de.quantity) number_of_pro,       
         sum(nvl(de.quantity,0) * nvl (p.costs,0)) total
from     items i 
         inner join de_details de on (i.items_no = de.item_no)
         inner join parts p on (de.pro_no = p.pro_no)
where    trunc(i.del_date, 'mm') = trunc(pram_date, 'mm')
group by i.condition,
         trunc(i.del_date, 'mm');
```

A few notes:

- You'll note that I have converted your old-style joins into ANSI join syntax.
- You had aliased the items table as "pros" but elsewhere in the query, the alias "i" was referenced. I believe this is what the alias for the items table should have been, so I updated it accordingly.
- I've converted your `to_char(... 'mm-yyyy')`s to `trunc(... 'mm')` as I believe that comparing columns in the same format as they're defined is more meaningful (leading to easier maintenance etc).

---

I'm not sure why you're getting the "not a group by expression" error, since it's working for me:

```
with     items as (select 1 items_no, 'a' condition, sysdate -1 del_date from dual union all
                   select 2 items_no, 'a' condition, sysdate del_date from dual union all
                   select 3 items_no, 'a' condition, sysdate + 31 del_date from dual),
    de_details as (select 1 item_no, 10 quantity, 1 pro_no from dual union all
                   select 2 item_no, 20 quantity, 2 pro_no from dual union all
                   select 3 item_no, 40 quantity, 1 pro_no from dual),
         parts as (select 1 pro_no, 100 costs from dual union all
                   select 2 pro_no, 200 costs from dual)
----- end of mimicking your tables with data in them
select   i.condition,
         trunc(i.del_date, 'mm') del_date,
         sum(de.quantity) number_of_pro,       
         sum(nvl(de.quantity,0) * nvl (p.costs,0)) total
from     items i 
         inner join de_details de on (i.items_no = de.item_no)
         inner join parts p on (de.pro_no = p.pro_no)
--where    trunc(i.del_date, 'mm') = trunc(pram_date, 'mm')
group by i.condition,
         trunc(i.del_date, 'mm');

CONDITION DEL_DATE  NUMBER_OF_PRO      TOTAL
--------- --------- ------------- ----------
a         01-JAN-16            30       5000
a         01-FEB-16            40       4000
```

Are you sure that you added the `trunc(..., 'mm')` to the colunn in both the select and group by colunn lists?

---

Here's how I'd write the procedure, assuming that I needed to loop through each of the rows returned by the query and display them via dbms_output:

```
create or replace procedure num_of_ret_can (pram_date in date)
as
  cursor cur2 is
    select   i.condition,
             trunc(i.del_date, 'mm') del_date,
             sum(de.quantity) number_of_pro,       
             sum(nvl(de.quantity,0) * nvl (p.costs,0)) total
    from     items i 
             inner join de_details de on (i.items_no = de.item_no)
             inner join parts p on (de.pro_no = p.pro_no)
    where    trunc(i.del_date, 'mm') = trunc(pram_date, 'mm')
    group by i.condition,
             trunc(i.del_date, 'mm');

  v_counter number := 0;
begin
  for cal_cur in cur2
  loop
    v_counter := v_counter + 1;

    if cal_cur.condition ='CANCELL' then -- are you sure? Not CANCEL?
      dbms_output.put_line('CANCELLED: '||cal_cur.number_of_pro );
      dbms_output.put_line('Total: '|| cal_cur.total);
    elsif cal_cur.condition ='ORDER RETURNED' then
      dbms_output.put_line('RETURNED              : '||cal_cur.number_of_pro);
      dbms_output.put_line('Total                 : '||cal_cur.total);

    elsif cal_cur.condition = 'ALL ORDERS ARE CANCELLED!' then
      dbms_output.put_line('ALL CANCELLATIONS     : '||cal_cur.number_of_pro );
      dbms_output.put_line('Total                 : '||cal_cur.total);
    end if;
  end loop;

  if v_counter = 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('No records for this month');
  end if;
end num_of_ret_can;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The query gives me an error saying: not a GROUP BY expression!!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting that error as it works for me (I've updated my answer with proof). Are you sure you added the `trunc(..., 'mm')` to both the select and group by column lists?

Comment: It did work for me now thank, but it loops twice anonymous block completed
Number of all cancellations    : 2
Total value                    : 39.98
  
Number of all items returns          : 11
Total value                    : 239.89
  
Number of all items returns          : 11
Total value                    : 239.89

Comment: There are no loops in your sample code. Also, you make reference to `VARCUR1`; where is that defined? Should that be `cal_cur`?

Comment: Yes, you are right I put VARCUR1 instead cal_cur, my bad!  The problem If I leave the procedure without a loop it gives me one condition, however, If I add the loop, it will loop number of times to show unnecessary results

Comment: I've added how I'd write the procedure into my question. However, I am curious as to how this procedure would be used - is this a homework type question? Because if it's not, I wouldn't advise writing the procedure like this - for a start, if the front end was asking for the results month-by-month, I'd simply open a ref-cursor for the query and pass that back for the front end to loop through.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have made the procedure as part of my studies not suitable for the work environment! I still have one more loop goes on, I copied the result just to show you what I mean: anonymous block completed
Number of cancelled            : 2
Total value                    : 39.98
  
Number of all items returns   : 7
Total value                   : 139.93
  
Number of all items returns   : 4
Total value                   : 99.96

Comment: Did you definitely amend the cursor in your procedure to group by the trunc(i.del_date, 'mm')? It seems like you might still be grouping by day, rather than month.

Comment: I've done to_char?! Does it effect ? as I am passing TO_DATE('01-2016','mm-yyyy') to it! :/

Comment: Exactly what did you put in the cursor?

Comment: Exactly the same as cursor cur2 is
    select   i.condition,
             i.del_date, 
             sum(de.quantity) number_of_pro,       
             sum(nvl(de.quantity,0) * nvl (p.costs,0)) total
    from     items i 
             inner join de_details de on (i.items_no = de.item_no)
             inner join parts p on (de.pro_no = p.pro_no)
    where    to_char(i.del_date, 'mm') = to_char(pram_date, 'mm')
    group by i.condition,
             to_char(i.del_date, 'mm'); I copied the code

Comment: that's not what I put. Did you completely miss the `select i.condition,  trunc(i.del_date, 'mm') del_date, ... group by i.condition, trunc(i.del_date, 'mm')` that I proposed way back in my original solution? You can't expect correct results if you haven't tried the solutions provided!

Comment: How do I pass a date of ('mm-yyyy') format to this procedure in order to verify it properly word by word

Comment: You mean, how do you call that procedure by passing in a date? If so, `begin NUM_OF_RET_CAN(to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')); end;`

Comment: I didn't try the TRUNC at the beginning as it came back with  expression is of wrong type. Therefore I tried to_char instead. I changed every to_char to trunc. However, how do I provoke the procedure, I want to pass (mm-yyyy)| !

Comment: you don't have to pass in something in mm-yyyy format; you're already doing a to_char(...'mm-yyyy') on the date parameter. So you just need to pass a date that is in the month you're querying for. So passing in 1st Jan 2016 would return the same as passing in the 30th Jan 2016. You could just amend the string and format mask in the to_date() to be 'mm-yyyy' though. eg. `begin NUM_OF_RET_CAN(to_date('01-2016', 'mm-yyyy')); end;`

Comment: I don't know how to thank you!! It worked perfectly better than ever!!

Comment: Thank you very much I almost cried sorting this out!!

Comment: I'm glad you got there in the end *{:-D

Comment: Cheers, Thank you pal you really made my day :-)

Comment: Hi Boneist, I am sorry for asking again, but I need your help if that's fine!

Comment: Your best bet would be to start a new question

Comment: I posted it few minutes ago but not sure if I can put the link here or not!?